# How to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder from Wordpress using AWS SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, plugin-development, javascript

Use Case:

The user uploads his video from the frontend of my website in any format he wants to Amazon S3. Now I want to covenrt that video file  to MPEG-4 using Amazon Elastic Transcoder by applying AWS SDK for PHP.

What is the best practice to do that if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a plugin to output the form using shortcode
2. Submit form using Ajax call
3. Fire off AWS-SDK calls within the form Ajax handler
4. Poll for Elastic Transcode job status, but SNS is preferrable
5. Push end result to Frontend User via Websocket or Email

Comment: Thanks. That's awesome. But just a short question: why i should use my own plugin to generate my upload form using short code, isn't it possible to use an already made form plugin (like contact form 7 or gravity forms) and their ajax calls ?

Comment: You could use those form plugins as long as you are able to manipulate the end result with hooks.

Comment: you mean the end results in the 5th step? Also do you know a good place or article to start for the 5th step, since i have not used Websocket before especially for Wordpress  and Amazon?

Comment: Websocket is very simple. You enqueue a library such as socket.io and place your custom js code inline.